# 教科書通りのプログラムですが、実行ができません。エラーメッセージ「weight_variable() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dtype'」

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation
from keras.layers.recurrent import SimpleRNN
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.utils import shuffle

np.random.seed(0)

def sin(x, T=100):
    return np.sin(2.0 * np.pi * x / T)

def toy_problem(T=100, ampl=0.05):
    x = np.arange(0, 2 * T + 1)
    noise = ampl * np.random.uniform(low=-1.0, high=1.0, size=len(x))
    return sin(x) + noise

'''
データの生成
'''
T = 100
f = toy_problem(T)
length_of_sequences = 2 * T
maxlen = 25  # ひとつの時系列データの長さ

data = []
target = []

for i in range(0, length_of_sequences - maxlen + 1):
    data.append(f[i: i + maxlen])
    target.append(f[i + maxlen])

X = np.array(data).reshape(len(data), maxlen, 1)
Y = np.array(target).reshape(len(data), 1)

# データ設定
N_train = int(len(data) * 0.9)
N_validation = len(data) - N_train

X_train, X_validation, Y_train, Y_validation = \
    train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=N_validation)

'''
モデル設定
'''
n_in = len(X[0][0])  # 1
n_hidden = 20
n_out = len(Y[0])  # 1

def weight_variable(shape, name=None):
    return np.random.normal(scale=.01, size=shape)

early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=10, verbose=1)

model = Sequential()

model.add(SimpleRNN(n_hidden,
                    kernel_initializer=weight_variable,
                    input_shape=(maxlen, n_in)))

model.add(Dense(n_out, kernel_initializer=weight_variable))

model.add(Activation('linear'))

optimizer = Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999)

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
              optimizer=optimizer)

'''
モデル学習
'''
epochs = 500
batch_size = 10

model.fit(X_train, Y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          validation_data=(X_validation, Y_validation),
          callbacks=[early_stopping])

'''
出力を用いて予測
'''
truncate = maxlen

Z = X[:1]  # 元データの最初の一部だけ切り出し

original = [f[i] for i in range(maxlen)]
predicted = [None for i in range(maxlen)]

for i in range(length_of_sequences - maxlen + 1):
    z_ = Z[-1:]
    y_ = model.predict(z_)
    sequence_ = np.concatenate(
        (z_.reshape(maxlen, n_in)[1:], y_),
        axis=0).reshape(1, maxlen, n_in)

    Z = np.append(Z, sequence_, axis=0)
    predicted.append(y_.reshape(-1))

'''
グラフで可視化
'''
plt.rc('font', family='serif')
plt.figure()
plt.ylim([-1.5, 1.5])
plt.plot(toy_problem(T, ampl=0), linestyle='dotted', color='#aaaaaa')
plt.plot(original, linestyle='dashed', color='black')
plt.plot(predicted, color='black')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

添付していただいたコードを私の環境にコピーして実行してみたところ、おそらく希望の結果が得られました

私の環境を示しますので、必要であればモジュールやPythonのアップデートをしてみてください
python: 3.7.5
numpy :1.18.1          
scikit-learn :0.22 
scipy :1.4.1
keras :2.2.4

### 更新

似たような問題に直面している質問を見つけました
https://teratail.com/questions/212547 質問サイト
https://keras.io/ja/initializers/ 質問サイトの参考サイト
この参考サイトページによると

> callable なオブジェクトを渡す場合には，初期化しようとする変数の shape と dtype を引数に取るように設計してください

ということで、dtypeの指定が必要だと思われます
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 欲しかった結果です！！確認します。ありがとうございました！！

Comment: 確認したところ、python3.77, numpy1.18.4, keras 2.3.1, scipy 1.4.1, sklearn 0.23.1でした。

Comment: 定義にdtypeを追加したところ、無事に求めていたものが表示されました！！ありがとうございました。

Comment: よろしければベストアンサーを付けていただけると今後の励みになりますので、よろしくお願いいたします